# Different frontNames for each store

Tags: frontend, routing, router

I've got a module which works fine, however I need a different frontName for each store.

The stores are 'english' and 'french', and as such, the frontName should be translated for each.

I've tried a couple of things in config XML, namely:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
     <modules>
        <Lw_Listbundles>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Lw_Listbundles>
     </modules>
     <frontend>
       <routers>
          <listbundles>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>Lw_Listbundles</module>
                 <frontName>bundles</frontName>
              </args>
           </listbundles>
          <listbundles>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>Lw_Listbundles</module>
                 <frontName>agencements</frontName>
              </args>
           </listbundles>
       </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <listbundles>
                <file>listbundles.xml</file>
            </listbundles>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <listbundles>
                <class>Lw_Listbundles_Block</class>
            </listbundles>
        </blocks>
    </global>

</config>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
     <modules>
        <Lw_Listbundles>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Lw_Listbundles>
     </modules>
     <frontend>
       <routers>
          <listbundles>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>Lw_Listbundles</module>
                 <frontName>bundles</frontName>
              </args>
           </listbundles>
       </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <listbundles>
                <file>listbundles.xml</file>
            </listbundles>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <listbundles>
                <class>Lw_Listbundles_Block</class>
            </listbundles>
        </blocks>
    </global>

    <stores>
        <french>
          <frontend>
              <routers>
              <listbundles>
                  <use>standard</use>
                  <args>
                     <module>Lw_Listbundles</module>
                     <frontName>agencements</frontName>
                  </args>
               </listbundles>

              </routers>
          </frontend>
        </french>
    </stores>

</config>
```

But I'm not getting much luck - I don't mind too much if both frontNames are available on both stores, but I do need both frontNames on way or another!

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are almost there.

In your first try, just make the route identifier  different for each route. Those identifiers should be unique, so if you set the same name, the second will override the first and only one route will be defined.

Change to some like this:

```
<listbundles_1>
    <use>standard</use>
        <args>
            <module>Lw_Listbundles</module>
            <frontName>bundles</frontName>
        </args>
</listbundles_1>
<listbundles_2>
    <use>standard</use>
        <args>
            <module>Lw_Listbundles</module>
            <frontName>agencements</frontName>
        </args>
</listbundles_2>
```

Both routes will be available in both stores but you can limit that in your controller code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your frontName configurable in the backend and allow the administrator to chose another for each store view. Then in your router, simply get the config and check if the requested frontName is one of yours.

I have answered a similar question here: [Customizable router frontName](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75655/customizable-router-frontname/75657#75657)