# Customizable router frontName

Tags: configuration, controllers, router

I have a router like this

```
<routers>
    <mymodule>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
            <module>NSP_MyModule</module>
            <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
        </args>
    </mymodule>     
</routers>
```

which (in my environment) will be accessable with this URL `/magento/mymodule`
but I want the URL key `mymodule` to be custamizable through backend. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far? Do you know how to create a module configuration with system.xml in general?

Comment: The system.xml should be managable. I don't know how to assign the variable to the frontName

Comment: Okay, what have you tried to achieve this, and why did it not work?

Comment: I have no idea how this can be done and I couldn't find a solution by googling. This actually bugs me for a while now, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 2):

In [this excellent post by Alan Storm,](http://alanstorm.com/magento_dispatch_routers) I found a hint to a possible solution. You should register your own router. An example can be found in Magento's CMS module.

In the CMS module's config.xml find this section:

```
<events>
    <controller_front_init_routers>
        <observers>
            <cms>
                <class>Mage_Cms_Controller_Router</class>
                <method>initControllerRouters</method>
            </cms>
        </observers>
    </controller_front_init_routers>
</events>
```

The method `initControllerRouters()` registers a new router:

```
public function initControllerRouters($observer)
{
    /* @var $front Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front */
    $front = $observer->getEvent()->getFront();

    $front->addRouter('cms', $this);
}
```

...that will be iterated in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:

```
while (!$request->isDispatched() && $i++<100) {
    foreach ($this->_routers as $router) {
        if ($router->match($this->getRequest())) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The match() method of the CMS-Router contains this code:

```
$page   = Mage::getModel('cms/page');
$pageId = $page->checkIdentifier($identifier, Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
if (!$pageId) {
    return false;
}

$request->setModuleName('cms')
    ->setControllerName('page')
    ->setActionName('view')
    ->setParam('page_id', $pageId);
```

...which leads to the file Cms/controllers/PageController.php. The class inside is named `Mage_Cms_PageController` and has a method `viewAction()` that asks for the request's parameter `page_id`. From here, you can look further at the method `Mage::helper('cms/page')->renderPage($this, $pageId)`.

I think another big problem will be, if the configured frontName matches that of a system frontName, or the frontName defined by another module. I have no idea how this might work out.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this, you need to manually add your dynamic routes to *Standard-Router*<sup>**1**</sup> before dispatching of router happens. I will show you how you can achieve this with an example below. Using which, you can implement rest.

You need to listen to the event `controller_front_init_routers` and add your routes in the observer.

File: `app\code\{codePool}\{Namespace}\{Module}\etc\config.xml`

```
<config>
    <global>
        <events>
            <controller_front_init_routers>
                <observers>
                    <add_dynamic_frontnames>
                        <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
                        <method>addDynamicFrontnames</method>
                    </add_dynamic_frontnames>
                </observers>
            </controller_front_init_routers>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

<sup>Note : Important. Observer should be inside global scope.</sup>

File : `app\code\{codePool}\{Namespace}\{Module}\Model\Observer.php`

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer
{
    const DYNAMIC_FRONTNAMES = 'sytem/config/path/to/dynamic/routes';

    public function addDynamicFrontnames(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        //get front controller
        $front = $observer->getEvent()->getFront();

        //grab request object and standard router
        $request = $front->getRequest();
        $standardRouter = $front->getRouter('standard');

        //grab module and route info using frontname;
        //note:a router with frontname 'mymodule' should be configured in your module
        $drouteName = $standardRouter->getRouteByFrontName('mymodule');
        $dmoduleName = $standardRouter->getModuleByFrontName('mymodule');

        //get dynamic frontnames from system config section
        $_dynamicFrontNames = explode(',',
            Mage::getStoreConfig()->getNode(self::DYNAMIC_FRONTNAMES)
        );

        //add your dynamic frontnames to standard router
        foreach ($_dynamicFrontNames as $frontName) {
            $standardRouter->addModule($frontName, $dmoduleName, $drouteName);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

What we are doing here is, we are using *Front-Controller*<sup>**2**</sup> to grab *Standard-Router*. Then we will collect *module-name* and *router-name* using our frontName `mymodule`. Then set the same *module-name* and *router-name* for every dynamic frontname which we collect from the system config section `sytem/config/path/to/dynamic/routes`. So all the frontnames which you configured from system config section will just behave like `mymodule` frontname here.

So along with these event setup, you are required to setup a router like this in your `config.xml` file.

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <{router_identifer}>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Namspace_Module</module>
                    <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </{router_identifer}>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Also you need to setup a `system.xml` file to configure your dynamic frontnames and replace the constant `DYNAMIC_FRONTNAMES` with the the right path in the observer file above.

Hope that makes sense.

---

<sup>1:Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard</sup>

<sup>2:Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front</sup>